# UPDATE query not functioning in MySQL 5.0

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, where-clause

I'm not completely sure what I'm doing wrong here I've looked through again and again for incorrectly placed quotes but I cannot for the life of me get this UPDATE query code to work... and I've troubleshooted it down to the query itself and it gives an incorrect syntax error, yet I have no idea what is wrong with it as it is identical to the manual.

```
$change = mysql_query("UPDATE Images SET Group='$group' WHERE ID = '$imgid'") or 
die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: What happens when you `echo "UPDATE Images SET Group='$group' WHERE ID = '$imgid'"`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you might need to do :

```
"UPDATE Images SET `Group`='$group' WHERE ID = '$imgid'"
```

as **group** is a keyword in MySQL .

Comment: Nice ah yeah I should have known that what a good catch. I was racking my brains out. Your code didn't work, but it led me to just change the fieldname alltogether, all working now.

Answer (score 0):

Well... if the update does not work this might have two reasons. Either your syntax is wrong; this should result in MySQL throwing an error which should show up with your `die(mysql_error())`.

Or there is simply no record matching your `WHERE`-condition. To check if any record was updated at all you might want to take a look at [mysql_affected_rows()](http://php.net/mysql_affected_rows). And you could run a `SELECT`-query on that table, using the same `WHERE`-condition.

Answer (score -1):

try this ..

"UPDATE Images SET `Group`='".$group."' WHERE ID = ".$imgid